# local-disk backed remote filesystem linux

Tags: amazon-s3, filesystems

Is there a way in Linux or any other *NIX platforms to have a remote filesystem mounted locally backed with a local filesystem backed caching.

I have some archive data on S3 that I need to access. The way they are accessed is; once touched application(s) need to read it off S3 several times.

I know I might be asking the file-system to to do the applications job of caching data; but the trouble is I do not have control on the application to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to work well under Solaris using CacheFS; local HDD space was allocated as the buffer, in which the contents of frequently-accessed NFS-mounted files were cached, and from which they were served if the CacheFS service determined that the contents on the NFS server remained unchanged since they were cached.  When I used it under Solaris, it worked well.

According to [the Wikipedia page on CacheFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CacheFS), it was ported to (rewritten for?) Linux, with the most recent release having been in the past year.

I can't comment on the Linux implementation, but assuming it does what the Solaris one used to do, I think it may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @MadHatter! Thats exactly what I was looking for! It went much further that what I expected. Per application profile for cache management... beautiful! Its a shame that the Linux port is lagging behind! More info here http://code.google.com/p/cachefs/wiki/ApplicationArchitecture

Answer (score 4):

[s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) has a caching option.

> If enabled via "use_cache" option,
>   s3fs automatically maintains a local
>   cache of files in the folder specified
>   by use_cache. Whenever s3fs needs to
>   read or write a file on s3 it first
>   downloads the entire file locally to
>   the folder specified by use_cache and
>   operates on it. When fuse release() is
>   called, s3fs will re-upload the file
>   to s3 if it has been changed. s3fs
>   uses md5 checksums to minimize
>   downloads from s3. Note: this is
>   different from the stat cache (see
>   below).
>
> Local file caching works by
>   calculating and comparing md5
>   checksums (ETag HTTP header).
>
> The folder specified by use_cache is
>   just a local cache. It can be deleted
>   at any time. s3fs re-builds it on
>   demand. Note: this directory grows
>   unbounded and can fill up a file
>   system dependent upon the bucket and
>   reads to that bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like mirroring the filesystem using a filesystem like [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/)? If not DRBD then there are others that could be used, it might give you a jump-off point from which to Google.

It's not caching in the real sense but it would duplicate the data locally and transmit changes to a remote system. Whether it's practical or not depends on how many changes you make to the files and why you are using S3 in the first place.

Comment: DRBD lloks very tempting, but it abstracts the block device as I understand. What I am after is something that abstracts the file-object. Again, the S3 already provides the network / remote file-system via s3fs. What I am after is some kind of glue ( similar to Unionfs). Thinking of which; Unionfs might be the answer to this.

Comment: I'm not an expert in it, but it does abstract the block device so you'd have a local copy to work on and the changes are synced up. You'd see a speed improvement since you're working on a local copy, which would be sort of what you were looking for with caching.

Answer (score -1):

There is `sshfs` which might be what you're looking for. My cursory understanding of sshfs is that it's a bit like using encrypted NFS mounts.

Comment: @Johnathan: [You need not post a "sig" or tagline in your answers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)

Comment: encryption != caching

Comment: Fair enough, points taken.